# I'm using guile 3 and trying to customize the "print" aspect of the repl

Tags: scheme, lisp, guile

I understand that the option `(repl-default-option-set! 'print ...)` is to be used  and i've tried so in many variations, i grokked the idea behind customizing the prompt `(repl-default-option-set! 'promp ">>>")` but can't seem to get the print aspect to work, ideally i would like to get rid of the increasing $num print that happens before the evalutations result

Comment: Write your own repl.

Comment: @alinsoar: if that actually is the best answer then someone needs to make the REPL control parameters more useful.

Comment: The standard REPL is quite complex and to manage it you need much experience (this happens in mit-scheme, where I know).  What I suggested you is valid for mit-scheme.  I am sure it is also valid principle in guile.

Comment: (In case you don't know, the `$num` values are actually useful since you can refer to them in your next inputs)

Answer (score 1):

You actually have an option to modify the printer by overriding write and display GOOPS generalized methods (this is done e.g. in python-on-guile repository https://gitlab.com/python-on-guile/python-on-guile). You can also overwrite the standard printer function entirely if you want total control, here is a simplified example (you need to be able to handle a port argument as well), this example only work for terminals that understand unix terminal escape sequence and is a bit hacky, you can find escape sequences at, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html

Add this to your .guile file

```
(use-modules (system repl common))

(define old-write (@ (guile) write))

(define (my-write . x)
  ;; reverse line feed
  (display (list->string '(#\Escape #\M)))

  ;; some other text
  (format #t "~%And the result is ...~%")
 
  (apply old-write x))

(repl-default-option-set! 'print
                      (lambda (repl obj)
                        (my-write obj)
                        (newline)))
```

Then a shell interaction in a unix escape terminal can look like

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (values 1 2)
And the result is ...
1
And the result is ...
2
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-cv/manual/html_node/Configuring-Guile_0027s-repl_002dprint-procedure.html

Answer (score 1):

You can change the options on the current repl with `repl-option-set!`. For example `(repl-option-set! (car (fluid-ref *repl-stack*)) 'print p)` will set the print function on the current repl. `repl-option-set!` and `*repl-stack*` are undocumented, but I don't think they're going anywhere. You should still use `repl-default-option-set!` to configure future repls, such as in `~/.guile`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer does indeed seem to be 'write your own REPL', which is extremely depressing.

Given:

```
(define p (lambda it (display "here") (newline))
```

Then two things happen:

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (repl-default-option-set! 'print p)
scheme@(guile-user)> 1
$6 = 1
```

So this doesn't work because you're setting some *default* option but the existing REPL has already chosen its printer.  If you convince the system to start a new REPL, for instance by getting into a break loop, you get this:

```
Entering a new prompt.  Type `,bt' for a backtrace or `,q' to continue.
scheme@(guile-user) [1]> 1
$7 = here
```

So the print function is indeed printing `here`, but that happens after the annoying `$7 =` thing (which I know has some purpose).

So, well, it looks like alinsoar's comment is correct, sadly: the REPL is customisable but ... not enough.

Answer (score 0):

`,o prompt ">_"` to change the prompt while already in a REPL